# PayPal Sandbox transactions are not showing for seller

Tags: testing, paypal, transactions, sandbox, accounts

I've used my live PayPal account to login to developer.paypal.com where I created 2 new accounts buyer@ (personal) and seller@ (business). I've implemented a PayPal plugin for a shop (CubeCart + PayPal Standard Payment Gateway plugin https://www.cubecart.com/extensions/payment-gateways/paypal-standard). When I complete an order (sandbox testing) I sign using buyer@ email and password and complete the order. I can then click to view account and it shows "payment to", "unclaimed" and the amount I've paid. When I logout of this account and login as my buyer@, I see no transactions. If I log back into developer.paypal.com and go to transactions under "Sandbox" section and select any of the email addresses I see the same statement for all of them "You don't have any transactions".

If I login to sandbox.paypal.com using james-facilitator@ account (business) there are no transactions here either.

If I login to sanbox.paypal.com using james-buyer@ account (personal) there is only the one initial transaction here for the initial 9,999 funds

I've obviously missed something but I can't think what, I'm not sure how a sandbox account knows who it's seller should be but I've checked both sandbox seller accounts. I find it strange that the buyer account I used has registered the transaction but it seems like it's orphaned as there isn't any other record of it any where else including the developer.paypal.com sandbox transaction. I've tried this several times to see if I could get it working and I've also allowed for 24 hours just in case there was a delay somewhere.

I just want to be able to test transactions before going live.

Any help/advice?

Much appreciated :)

Cheers

James

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an issue with what I've done/missed or perhaps a technical glitch somewhere. For the amount of views I've had over the past 3-4 days I've clearly addressed an issue that people can't help with. On this note, I've contacted PayPal support to see if they can help and I will update this answer so that future searchers can address the same issue and hopefully find resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Solved - silly really now I know but it was simply the email address I used to test the API. I used my main live account and I should have used the fake email address in my API call. Since my live controls the test accounts I assumed that this should have been used.