# PayPal sandbox accounts don't show transactions

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, lumen, omnipay

I'm trying to test my PayPal-Express checkout and it looks like it works fine, but after the redirects there are no transactions in both of the accounts.

I know there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520206/paypal-sandbox-transactions-are-not-showing-for-seller), but my config has the right credentials.

---

What I have:

1. Lumen app
2. Omnipay extension
3. sandbox buyer account - status: complete
4. sandbox shop account - status: complete

The Omnipay lib is configured with the credentials (username, password, signature) of the sandbox shop account

The purchase script looks like this:

```
$gateway = Omnipay::gateway('paypal');

$response = Omnipay::purchase([
    'currency' => 'EUR',
    'amount' => '100.00',
    'returnUrl' => 'http://localhost:8000/return',
    'cancelUrl' => 'http://localhost:8000/cancel',
])->send();

$response->redirect();
```

It's doing the redirect to PayPal, PayPal accepts then the payment with the buyers sandbox account and redirects me back to the `returnUrl` but both of the accounts have no balance changes and no transactions visible on their dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using PayPal express checkout to accept payment from your buyers. PayPal express checkout completes the payment in the 2 below steps:

1. **SetExpressCheckout** **API**: It initiates the payment & redirects the buyer to PayPal for approval. To know more, [click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
2. **DoExpressCheckoutPayment** **API**: It completes the express Checkout transaction and transfers the amount from the buyer to the Merchant PayPal business account. To know more, [click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

To resolve your issue, please check your code & call DoExpressCheckoutPayment API to complete the transaction and deduct the amount from the buyer's account.

If the issue still persists, [contact](https://paypal-techsupport.com) PayPal MTS for better assistance.

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm in a meeting now. I'll check it in an hour.